# Lua - getting nested table element

Tags: json, lua, nested

i have JSON responce like this:

```
{"ts":"1026","updates":

[{"type":"message_new","object":{"message":

{"date":1588966108,"from_id":329211115,"id":0,"out":0,"peer_id":2000000003,"text":"test"}}},

{"type":"message_new","object":{"message": 

{"date":1588966109,"from_id":329211115,"id":0,"out":0,"peer_id":2000000003,"text":"test2"}}}]}
```

How to print an "text" field?

I have this responce converted to Lua table.

I tried to call

```
answer["updates"]["object"]["message"]["text"]
```

, but i had error 'attempt to index a nil value (field 'object')'

Answer (score 2):

`updates` is an array. So use

```
answer["updates"][1]["object"]["message"]["text"]
```

or

```
answer.updates[1].object.message.text
```

Comment: `print(answer["updates"][1]["object"]["message"]["text"])` return error 'attempt to index a nil value (field '?')'

Comment: @385i, inspect your table with `for k,v in pairs(answer.updates) do print(k,v) end`